# Linq to XML parses files in a folder

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

So I have this code building with no errors but I need to alter how its opening the xml documents. Right now it can open a single xml documents what I need it to do is open up a folder on my c: and parse through all the xml files in the folder. Any help?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\.cfg");  //Change here
    var query = from x in doc.Descendants("X")
                select new
                {
                    Max1 = x.Attribute("Max").Value,
                    Min2 = x.Attribute("Min").Value
                };
    foreach (var x in query) ;
    Console.WriteLine("X");
    var query2 = from x in doc.Descendants("Y")
                 select new
                 {
                     Max3 = x.Attribute("Max").Value,
                     Min4 = x.Attribute("Min").Value
                 };
    foreach (var x in query2)
        Console.WriteLine("Y");
    var query3 = from x in doc.Descendants("ZA")
                 select new
                 {
                     Max5 = x.Attribute("Max").Value,
                     Min6 = x.Attribute("Min").Value
                 };
    foreach (var x in query3)
        Console.WriteLine("Z");
}
```

Comment: Please format your code by indenting it with four spaces, or clicking the `{ }` button in the editing toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop through `Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Something", "*.xml")`.

Comment: Thank you. Should I take out that line:                                                         XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\Sciclone UAC.cfg")                    and replace it with that? Will that line be able to parse through all the files in the folder?

Comment: You would pass the loop variable (which contains the strings returned by `EnumerateFiles`) to `Load`

Comment: I'm sorry I'm kinda new to c# I don't understand what you mean. Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Something", "*.xml"); XDocument doc = XDocment.load( what goes here)

Comment: You need to use a `foreach` loop.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx

Answer (score 0):

... A slightly more "declarative" manner:

```
// Program.cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string path = @"C:\stuff";
        Parallel.ForEach(Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.xml"), x => Walk(XDocument.Load(x)));
    }

    static IEnumerable<Calib> MapItem(IEnumerable<XElement> elements)
    {
        return elements.Select(x => new Calib
        {
            Max = x.Attribute("Max").Value,
            Min = x.Attribute("Min").Value
        });
    }

    static void Walk(XDocument doc)
    {
        var xitems = MapItem(doc.Descendants("XaxisCalib"));
        xitems.Iter(x => Console.WriteLine("(XaxisCalib) X: Min = {0} | Max = {1}", x.Min, x.Max));

        var yitems = MapItem(doc.Descendants("YAxisCalib"));
        yitems.Iter(x => Console.WriteLine("(YaxisCalib) Y: Min = {0} | Max = {1}", x.Min, x.Max));

        var zitems = MapItem(doc.Descendants("ZAxisCalib"));
        zitems.Iter(x => Console.WriteLine("(ZaxisCalib) Z: Min = {0} | Max = {1}", x.Min, x.Max));
    }
}

// Exts.cs
public static class Exts
{
    public static void Iter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            action(item);
        }
    }
}

// Calib.cs
public class Calib
{
    public string Max { get; set; }
    public string Min { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wow that look much more easier than my version. One thing I noticed though shouldnt this be at beginning of code sicne it needs to open the xm document before it begins parsing:                      static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        const string path = @"C:\stuff"; 
        Parallel.ForEach(Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.xml"), x => Walk(XDocument.Load(x))); 
    } 
}

Comment: @Casey, Dosen't matter where the `Main` method is placed, since its the first method that will be invoked when the application starts. Although I've moved it to the top for clarification.

Comment: Also whats the significance of the Exts.cs and Calib.cs codes should i open up a whole new console application for that or how do i intergrate that in?

Comment: @Casey, to keep things organized, I would recommend creating a new class file for both of those. (Right click the project name, click "Add" and then "Class").

Comment: It does not like this line: static IEnumerable<Calib> MapItem(IEnumerable<XElement>elements)                                                                       
Are you familiar with this error: The non generic types Systems.Collections.IEnumberable cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: @Casey, You should open the namespace `System.Collections.Generic` - You can do this by adding `using System.Collections.Generic;` to the top.

Comment: Instead of writing the values to the screen could I save them as a dataset in order to integrate to an excel spreadsheet?

Comment: @Casey, I think it would be better if you created a new question about that, since its have nothing to do with the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just writing the values out to the console, you could create a new Xml document from the values in the files and do whatever you want with from that (generate an Excel spreadsheet?):

```
var fileData = new XElement("root",
 from file in New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Something").GetFiles() 
    where file.Extension.Equals(".xml", String Comparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) 
    Let doc = XElement.Load(file.FullName)
    select new XElement("File", 
      new XAttribute("Path", file.FullName), 
      select new XElement("XAxisCalibs", 
         from x in doc.Descendants("XAxisCalib") 
         select new XElement("XAxisCalib", 
              new XAttribute("Max", x.Attribute("Max").Value),
              new XAttribute("Min", x.Attribute("Min").Value)
         )
      ),
      select new XElement("YAxisCalibs", 
         from y in doc.Descendants("YAxisCalib") 
         select new XElement("YAxisCalib", 
              new XAttribute("Max", x.Attribute("Max").Value),
              new XAttribute("Min", x.Attribute("Min").Value)
         )
      ),
      select new XElement("ZAxisCalibs", 
         from z in doc.Descendants("ZAxisCalib") 
         select new XElement("ZAxisCalib", 
              new XAttribute("Max", x.Attribute("Max").Value),
              new XAttribute("Min", x.Attribute("Min").Value)
         )
      )
    );
```

Granted, since this is complete declarative and one long statement, it is a bit of a trick to debug if necessary.

Comment: Thank you I will try  to debug and see waht I come up wit.